# LSTM model summary for multiclass classification

Tags: lstm, multiclass-classification

I am beginner in deep learning. Creating LSTM multiclass classification model for text data. It has  9 classes.[The layers of the model as shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqvhr.png)

After running this code i am getting the model summary as shown below. [Model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFWNZ.png)

As can see there are zero parameters in input layer. Is it right?
Please help me to understand this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The input layer only gets data with this shape: `(None,50)`
It means the model will get N datapoints having 50 features for each.
In TF2/Keras this is the way to create an input layer with the aforementioned dimensions: `(50,)` - No need to mention that this is a tuple.